# Why are these answers different? Which one is correct? (Distance between to two 3D points)

Tags: geometry, wolfram-alpha

I am calculating the distance between two 3D points in a program I am writing and using this math:

```
Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x2 - x1, 2) + Math.pow(y2 - y1, 2) + Math.pow(z2 - z1, 2))
```

[Wolfram Alpha Query #1, same as my answer](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt%20((1698336.0-1927176.0)%5E2%20%2B%20(-6147953.0-%20-6134094.0)%5E2%20%2B%20(91.0%20-%2051610.0)%5E2))  == 234,976.6474396

[Wolfram Alpha Query #2, different than my answer](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=distance+between+(1698336.0,-6147953.0,91.0)+and+(1927176.0,-6134094.0,51610.0)) == 234,977

Which one is correct? Why are they different?

Comment: Are they different?!

Comment: 234,977 vs 234976.6474396. About .4 different which is kinda big

Comment: Must be a wolfram alpha rounding bug.

Comment: Just curious - what do you get if you just square, or multiply by itself, rather than calling `Math.pow`?

Comment: @EthanBolker If you look at the WA links given, that's what he has done there. Still the same difference. I also get 234,977 when I subtract the two vectors and ask about the length of the difference.

Comment: It looks like the "distance between" function is is only reporting as many significant figures as your input data. Does WA have a policy on what kind of rounding they do?

Comment: @user275313 no, every input value has one figure after the period.

Comment: "About .4 different which is kinda big"  No it's very very small as the inputs were of maginitude of 10^6.  One assume the input was only significant to 6 figures so there no point for the solution to be significant much past that.  It's just distance was written to round.  square root was not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the same effect if you ask for [sqrt(1+1)](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt(1%2B1)) versus [distance between (0,0) and (1,1)](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=distance%20between%20(0,0)%20and%20(1,1)): the `sqrt` result has zillions of significant figures, but the `distance` result has only 6.

So this looks like a deliberate design decision, but I'm blowed if I can understand it.

Comment: I'll bet 'distance between' sends it off for some natural language parsing pre-processing which makes some assumptions that the user want a more "conversational" response, while the first query directly calls low-level functions.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck: $1.41421$ is not an integer.